# Static dispatching to correct member method with hierarchies of aggregate types

Tags: c++, c++11

I have written a small in-house framework which does something akin to:

```
Group<ObjectA1, ObjectA2> groupA(data);
Group<ObjectB> groupB(data);

// Compiles, as desired:
groupA.get<ObjectA1>();
groupA.get<ObjectA2>();
groupB.get<ObjectB>();

// Compilation errors (static asserts), as desired:
groupA.get<ObjectB>();
groupB.get<ObjectA1>();
groupB.get<ObjectA2>();
```

In short: a (variable) number of objects can be grouped together. Then the group can be queried for objects whose type is encoded in the group type. For all other objects, a compilation error occurs.

Next, I'd like to extend it with the following abilities:

```
// ...continued...

using GroupA = Group<ObjectA1, ObjectA2>;
using GroupB = Group<ObjectB>;
AggregateGroup<GroupA, GroupB> group(groupA, groupB);

// Compiles, as desired
group.get<ObjectA1>();
group.get<ObjectA2>();
group.get<ObjectB>();

// Compilation error, as desired:
group.get<ObjectC>();
```

This can be generalized to groups consisting of other groups. Runtime solutions are easy, but I'm at a loss on how to do this at compile time.

**Question:** How can we create hierarchies of aggregate types that statically dispatch to the correct member?

A minimal version of my current implementation can be found at http://cpp.sh/8f4l

Comment: A minimal example is always useful.  Also if you've instantiated group with GroupA and GroupB, why would you expect ObjectC to be compatible with it?  What is the type of ObjectC?

Comment: @Robinson: Thanks for looking into it. As for your requested clarifications: (I) ObjectC is the type, which is neither in GroupA nor in GroupB; (ii) You wouldn't expect it to be compatible but you want to be made aware of any errors at compile time and not at runtime.

Comment: But your code comment says, "Compilation error, as desired".

Comment: I apologize if my intent isn't clear enough. I'll try to clarify. Given a group, I would like to be able to provide compile-time error checking on the requested object type based on the type of the group. Somewhere in the group type, the supported object types are encoded. But I'm not sure how I can exploit this correctly. I hope this is clearer. Thanks again for taking the time.

Comment: If you can make a minimal example that we can compile, perhaps on http://cpp.sh/ or similar, that would be useful.

Comment: @Robinson: I've updated the question with a link to a minimal version of what I currently have. I hope this makes what I'm trying to achieve clear.

Comment: Thank you for updating your question. Just want to make sure, do you expect `AggregateGroup` also takes variable number of `Groups` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is essentially how to get the *actual template argument* `ObjectA` from  `GroupA` inside `AggregateGroup`. Please see the example below (I simplify your example for easier understanding)

```
#include <type_traits>
using namespace std;

template <class T, class T1=char>
struct Group 
{
    typedef T _T;
    typedef T1 _T1;
};

template <class U, class U2>
class AggregateGroup 
{
    public:
    template <class C>
    void get(C x){
        static_assert(is_same<C,typename U::_T>::value || is_same<C,typename U2::_T>::value, "Failed");
        // You will need to add complex conditional expression here , this one is simplified than your case
    }
};

using GroupA = Group<int, double>; //=== Group<ObjectA1, ObjectA2>
using GroupB = Group<bool>;        //=== Group<ObjectB>

int main(){
    AggregateGroup<GroupA,GroupB> g; 
    g.get(1);      // this will compile because type of C is `int`
    g.get(true);   // this will compile because type of C is `bool`
    // g.get(2.0); // This will NOT compile because type of C is `double`
    return 0;
}
```

The trick above is `is_same<C,typename U::_T>` where `_T` is a `typedef` in template `Group`.

If you try to compile the line `g.get<double>(2.0)`, the compiler will complain:

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of 'void AggregateGroup<U, U2>::get(C) [with C = double; U = Group<int, double>; U2 = Group<bool, double>]':
main.cpp:29:15:   required from here
main.cpp:17:9: error: static assertion failed: Failed
         static_assert(is_same<C,typename U::_T>::value || is_same<C,typename U2::_T>::value, "Failed");
```

### Update (variadic template )

Your code is already very clost to the solution. The only thing that needs to change is removing the wraper `ObjectRetriever`:

```
template<typename... Objects> class AggGroup;

template<typename Object, typename... Objects>
class AggGroup<Object, Objects...> : public Object, public AggGroup<Objects...>
   {
   public:
      explicit AggGroup(Context &context)
         : Object(context)
         , AggGroup<Objects...>(context)
         {
         }

      template<typename ObjectType>
      bool get()
         {
         static_assert(
            std::is_base_of<ObjectRetriever<ObjectType>, AggGroup>::value,
            "Object type not in object space"
            );

         return static_cast<ObjectRetriever<ObjectType> &>(*this).get();
         }
   };

template<>
class AggGroup<>
   {
   public:
      explicit AggGroup(Context &context)
         {
         }
   };
```

Try the following usage

```
using GroupA = ObjectGroup<ObjectA>;
using GroupB = ObjectGroup<ObjectB, ObjectC>;
AggGroup<GroupA, GroupB> group(context);
group.get<int>();     // not compile
group.get<ObjectB>(); // OK
```

Complete code [here](http://cpp.sh/9xhr).

Comment: Unfortunately, this is more than a simplification. In your example, class B is not actually an aggregate group as it contains only one type. So to continue with your example: if you have B<U1, U2>, how would you do the dispatch for a given C?

Comment: Essentially U1 is just duplication of U2, you can add as many as you want, just repeating the `static_assert` lines.

Comment: Although I think it is not necessary, I will add `U2` to my example.

Comment: I don't see how that answers my question. If you could demonstrate the dispatching step, I'd appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: Aside from the fact that your updated example is not doing the dispatch, the code works with only two types. I should have made it clear that a group may aggregate a variable number of object types, so apologies for that. Updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Pls check the updated answer. Hope I don't miss something.

Comment: Managed to solve the issue yesterday. Will accept this as the answer as it contains the gist of what is required. Thank you though for taking the effort, much appreciated!